Excel cell referencing in external sheet
I would like to reference a cell in another sheet in another folder1\file1.xlsx 'Ref' sheet as follows.
I have 2 sheets, sheet1 and sheet2. Sheet2 is a workbook in another folder 'folder1' and file 'file1.xlsx' and workbook 'Ref', not open.
Sheet 1 is the current sheet.
Sheet1 has A12 = 21, U12 = ='D:\folder1[file1.xlsx]Ref'!K21
This works fine. If I insert into T12 =INDIRECT("a"&ROW()), this returns 21. Therefore, this formula works obtaining the row number wanted.
However, if I try to use this formula as the row number in the original U12 cell it fails:
='D:\folder1[file1.xlsx]Ref'!KINDIRECT("a"&ROW())
I receive #Name?
How do I use the contents of A12 as the row number to access the contents of the cell at K21 in the 'Ref' workbook that is not open?

INDIRECT function does not read from closed workbooks. You can use INDEX instead, e.g.
=INDEX('D:\folder1[file1.xlsx]Ref'!K:K,INDIRECT("a"&ROW()))

